# Error reproducing Eland Demo Notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to reproduce Python Elasticsearch client Eland notebook, available in [Eland documentation](https://eland.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#).

Here are the first lines of code for producing an eland dataframe from my local Elasticsearch index called `sensor_index`:

```
import eland as ed
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

ed_sensors = ed.read_es(localhost,'sensor_index')
```

Unfortunately, in line 1, occurs the following `Import error`:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic' (/home/user/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/generic.py)`

Pandas v.1.3.1 is being used.

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, eventually I found out that Eland version 7.13.0b1 turns out with the Pandas v.1.3.1.

After downgrading to Pandas v.1.2.5 everything turned out ok.